# Windows Desktop Gadgets crash

Tags: windows-7, crash, desktop-gadget

I suddenly started getting

"Windows Desktop Gadgets has stopped working."

The crash details are:

```
Problem signature:
  Problem Event Name:   APPCRASH
  Application Name: sidebar.exe
  Application Version:  6.1.7100.0
  Application Timestamp:    49ee9780
  Fault Module Name:    kernel32.dll
  Fault Module Version: 6.1.7100.0
  Fault Module Timestamp:   49eeaac7
  Exception Code:   c0000005
  Exception Offset: 0000000000003892
  OS Version:   6.1.7100.2.0.0.256.1
  Locale ID:    1033
  Additional Information 1: d8fd
  Additional Information 2: d8fd8161e9ac0930383dc216f4c34d70
  Additional Information 3: a87e
  Additional Information 4: a87eb7be9617da7857e04259db193484
```

It happened while in the midst of installing the software that comes with Logitech's Webcam Pro 9000, which might be related, but it won't start at all any more. Using Windows 7 RC build 7100.

Comment: *Windows 7 RC Build 7100* <----- You see right there is your problem :) (Yes I am aware that the fact that you can't do a direct upgrade is bugging you and why you still use the RC, but I just couldn't resist)

Comment: As soon as I have a few free minutes, I'll upgrade to RTM!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would first suggest that you try and restore the Default Gadgets. From [here](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/10215-gadgets-restore-default-gadgets.html):

> - Control Panel
> - Appearance and Personalization
> - Restore desktop gadgets installed with Windows

This should reset the setting and get it working. Also according to my understanding the Gadgets will **NOT** work if you have UAC disabled. If you prefer not to be bugged by the popup confirming permission you can change to silent elevation as described on TechNet [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc507861.aspx):

> - Log on to a Windows Vista computer with an administrator account in Admin Approval Mode.
> - Click the Start button, click Run, type secpol.msc, and then click OK.
> - At the User Account Control dialog box for the Microsoft Management Console, click Continue.
> - In Local Security Settings, expand Local Security Settings, expand Local Policies, and then expand Security Options.
> - Right click the User Account Control: Behavior of the elevation prompt for administrators in Admin Approval Mode setting and select Properties.

Lastly, uninstall the Logitec Software and see if the problem still exists. The few references I have seen to this error seems to be related to the Logitech software, and it may be worthwhile (althought I suspect you have already) to check for newer drivers, or alternatively check if there is newer drivers on Windows Update. If the drivers is not the problem and it's the software to control the device, you may be out of luck. I am not aware of any replacement software, but most messenger client for examples can natively read the cams without the need for the official software.

<sub>Disclaimer: As a rule I never install the software that comes with the device, I rarely if ever use it or need it</sub>

Comment: The part that worked for me was "uninstalling the logitech software." Thanks!

Comment: yah, windows7 rc1 and definitively the logitech stuff "webcam pro 9000". finally!

Answer (score 0):

If you kill the LVPrS64H.exe and LVPrcSrv.exe processes, it will start working.  And then you can uninstall the logitech webcam software without rebooting.