# Windows 7 Sidebar crashes

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit, sidebar

In Windows 7 (Professional 64-bit) my sidebar.exe will crash roughly every 10 hours and it has been doing this for about 7 month now (at least that is the earliest entry in the event log). I found [this](https://superuser.com/questions/39791/windows-desktop-gadgets-crash) question which is similar, however, the fault module is different, I am *not* using the Win7 RC and I do not have a Logitech webcam.

While this does not impact my ability to use the computer at all, especially as the exe will immediately be restarted, it is annoying and any help resolving it is appreciated.

**Event Properties:**

General tab

> Faulting application name: sidebar.exe, version: 6.1.7600.16385, time stamp: 0x4a5bc613
>   Faulting module name: ntdll.dll, version: 6.1.7600.16559, time stamp: 0x4ba9b29c
>   Exception code: 0xc0000005
>   Fault offset: 0x00036fd8
>   Faulting process id: 0xca4
>   Faulting application start time: 0x01cb7c201006c6a0
>   Faulting application path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Sidebar\sidebar.exe
>   Faulting module path: C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ntdll.dll
>   Report Id: 468391e2-e864-11df-8c50-6cf0490fb520

Detail tab (as XML)

```
- <Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
- <System>
  <Provider Name="Application Error" /> 
  <EventID Qualifiers="0">1000</EventID> 
  <Level>2</Level> 
  <Task>100</Task> 
  <Keywords>0x80000000000000</Keywords> 
  <TimeCreated SystemTime="2010-04-05T13:11:14.000000000Z" /> 
  <EventRecordID>802</EventRecordID> 
  <Channel>Application</Channel> 
  <Computer>TIMA</Computer> 
  <Security /> 
  </System>
- <EventData>
  <Data>sidebar.exe</Data> 
  <Data>6.1.7600.16385</Data> 
  <Data>4a5bc613</Data> 
  <Data>ntdll.dll</Data> 
  <Data>6.1.7600.16385</Data> 
  <Data>4a5bdb3b</Data> 
  <Data>c0000005</Data> 
  <Data>00037008</Data> 
  <Data>9d4</Data> 
  <Data>01cad3a88ad47e87</Data> 
  <Data>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Sidebar\sidebar.exe</Data> 
  <Data>C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ntdll.dll</Data> 
  <Data>b5ebcdd1-40b4-11df-bb88-6cf0490fb520</Data> 
  </EventData>
  </Event>
```